# I want to link my application back button to android mobile builtin back button

Tags: java, android, back-button

I tried many ways but find out that linking my application to the android back button will be easy for my application but didn't find anyway. If anyone can help me out how can I link so when I press the android mobile back icon my application will also move to back category. Working on Android Studio, API 25.

Comment: try calling super.onBackPressed()  or overriding onBackPressed() based on what you need.

Comment: I tried and application force to stop and quit.

Comment: What does the log says about force stop  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try override this method:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            //Your intent
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Or if is your back button from toolbar use this

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                //your intent
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```